# Display Many Points With Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I know how to add point to map.

```
private void addMarkertoMap() {

        LatLng MarkerPos = new LatLng (24.803751, 1.479969);

        googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()

        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE))
        .position(MarkerPos)
        );
```

But what if I have many points (hundreds) and I want to display them from GML or KML file? Is it posible in Google Maps Android API? Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: @Waza_Be How to do that?

Comment: Have you read my answer and my comments, that will work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add just those markers that are currently visible on screen (though please note that you'll want to keep track of those markers that you add on-screen so that you don't add them over and over again. You may even want to remove those that are no longer visible)

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
      final LatLngBounds screenBounds = mMapView.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
      for (YourPoint point : mPoints) {
         if (screenBounds.contains(point.getLatLng()) {
            mMapView.addMarker(point.getLatLng());
         }
      } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question: yes, it is possible.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { addMarker(/* Something*/); }
```

Now, it's maybe time to think.. Do you really need to display hundreds of points on a map?
Maybe you could only display the 20 closest points, or the 30 more relevants...

Can you please redifine your question so we could answer and understand what you want.

It's very hard to understand what you want and where is the question.

Comment: I have 452 points (Lat Lon) in GML file and I have to display them on the map. My question is how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: @Vis: "how to do that?" -- call `addMarker()` 452 times. Though I agree with Waza_Be that your users will be unimpressed with the usability of your app.

Comment: @Vis for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  addMarker(/* Something*/);
}